# error: package android.support.multidex does not exist whem upgrading from minSdkVersion 16 to minSdkVersion 23

Tags: android, android-multidex

My app is not supporting Android 4.x and 5.x anymore, only Android 6.0 and higher. For that reason, in my `app/build.gradle` I changed `minSdkVersion 16` to `minSdkVersion 23`. After doing that, I have started to get this error when I try to run the app:

```
error: package android.support.multidex does not exist
error: cannot find symbol variable MultiDex
```

In one of my `.java` files, I see the errors in the following lines:

```
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
MultiDex.install(this);
```

Should I simply not use `MultiDex` because Android 6.0 and higher do not need that anymore? This is considering that my app will not support Android 5.x and lower anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add the following in Dependencies in build.gradle (:app):

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Isn't `implementation` the modern way to write that, instead of `compile`?

Comment: yes sir i just copied it from a old project of mine :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I used `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` as you suggested, and it works now. Problem fixed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: Not really. I tried that and it did not fix the error. The solution was what I already marked as the best answer. Thank you Arejectednobody.

Comment: Glad it was fixed!

Comment: Yes, it was. Thank you.

Comment: This also works for minSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change

`import android.support.multidex.MultiDex`

to

`import androidx.multidex.MultiDex`

to reference the "newer" `MultiDex`'s location (version 1.0.3 in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting multiDexEnabled true in build.gradle(app)

Comment: I already have `multiDexEnabled true` in my `defaultConfig{}` section of `app/build.gradle`.

Comment: I too had similar issues. Had my minSdkVersion set to 19. Hope it might help

Comment: Thanks. The solution was using `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`, as Ismail Alaoui recommended to me in the answer that I chose as the best answer. Thank you P. Anantha.